# Which function is right hook point to capture info of packets kernel has received?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ebpf

I want to use eBPF to monitor how many bytes the a  K8s pod has sent to and received  from out side cluster. I guess tracepoints at `/net/*` should work, but I find the only output traffic goes through these tracepoints (e.g. `net:net_dev_xmit`)  so what about the incoming traffic ?

Here is the example,the result shows incoming traffic do not trigger `netif_receive_skb` or `netif_rx`.

```bash
❯ sudo perf trace --no-syscall --event 'net:*' curl example.com > /dev/null
     0.000 :3786880/3786880 net:net_dev_queue(skbaddr: 0xffff894b2703cc00, len: 71, name: "eno1")
     0.009 :3786880/3786880 net:net_dev_start_xmit
     0.012 :3786880/3786880 net:net_dev_xmit(skbaddr: 0xffff894b2703cc00, len: 71, name: "eno1")
     0.015 :3786880/3786880 net:net_dev_queue(skbaddr: 0xffff894b2703c900, len: 71, name: "eno1")
     0.016 :3786880/3786880 net:net_dev_start_xmit
     0.018 :3786880/3786880 net:net_dev_xmit(skbaddr: 0xffff894b2703c900, len: 71, name: "eno1")
   171.319 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_queue(skbaddr: 0xffff894b45c9cee0, len: 74, name: "eno1")
   171.326 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_start_xmit
   171.330 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_xmit(skbaddr: 0xffff894b45c9cee0, len: 74, name: "eno1")
  1352.743 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_start_xmit()
  1352.745 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_xmit(skbaddr: 0xffff894b45c9cce0, len: 141, name: "eno1")
  1993.436 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_queue(skbaddr: 0xffff894b45c9d4e0, len: 66, name: "eno1")
  1993.444 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_start_xmit(name: "eno1", skbaddr: 0xffff894b45c9d4e0)
  1993.446 curl/3786879 net:net_dev_xmit(skbaddr: 0xffff894b45c9d4e0, len: 66, name: "eno1")
```

**Because  I want to eBPF program ioslates from host network (do not share network namespace) and exclude in-cluster network tarffic, So `tcp_sendmgs` and `tcp_recvmsg` are not suitable hook point.**

Thank you for very much if you could give some suggestion.

**PS**: I remove inrelative info of `perf trace`  for simplicity.

Comment: Did you consider using a tc-bpf hook point? Which Kubernetes CNI are you using? What interfaces exist will depend on the CNI.

Comment: @pchaigno Thank you for reply! I use Calico.The `perf trace` command executes in my developing PC (no k8s env). Honestly,I am not faimliar with tc-bpf hooks.Does it require newer kernel version?  Because the kernel versions of our cluster servers are mainly 4.9.x and 4.19.x, I am afraid that some features cannot be used.

Comment: With Calico, AFAIK, each pod has its own interface on the host (`caliXXX`). You can attach a BPF program to that interface to count the number of bytes received and sent by that container. Linux 4.9 has all the features required to do that (you can even run a full-fledge eBPF-based CNI like Cilium on 4.9 so counting packets shouldn't be an issue ;) ).

Comment: Do you only want to count traffic sent and received from outside the cluster (i.e., not e.g. pod-to-pod)?

Comment: @pchaigno Yeah, I dont care the traffic between pods. The only thing I want to konw is how many bytes sent and received from through bonding interfaces(e.g. bond0,bond1). The scenario is that because the trafffic at L4 (`tcp_sendmsg` and `tcp_recvmsg`)layer goes through interface likes `calixxxx`  that i cannot figure out whether traffic is sent to server locates inside cluster or outside of cluster.  So I choose to use tracepoint at L2 layer`net:net_dev_xmit`.

Comment: Do you have a CIDR that matches all intra-cluster traffic? That is, a CIDR that includes pod and node IP addresses.

Comment: @pchaigno I have considiered using CIDR to filter traffic, but it is not able to cope with all clusters because some clusters have 10.0.0.0/16 and others use 192.168.0.0/16. Indeed, I can write CIDR into  configuration file and filtering destination IP addr, but I think it is not portable if I want to use this traffic monitor on a new cluster has new CIDR I need to add new CIDR configuration. That's why I choose to filter traffic by interfaces name at L2 layer.

Comment: After some googling, tc-bpf seems a better way to count traffic. Thanks for your suggestion. By the way, it's my first question asked on stackoverflow and I really appreciate you give me some hint. :D

Comment: To make the CIDR configurable, you could use a BPF LPM map (4.11+) or BPF global data (5.2+).

Comment: Hi, I am trying to learn tc-bpf but I cannot find some tutorials abot this. Do you know that? thanks beforehand.